# How to Show an Image as Pop Up Using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to do the samething that is happening in below Fiddle

> http://jsfiddle.net/6CR2H/1/

Still I done this

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="pop">
    <img src="http://patyshibuya.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/04.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;">
</a>

<a href="#" class="pop">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;">
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">              
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
        $('.pop').on('click', function() {
            $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
            $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
        });     
});
</script>
```

But It's not Working , I also include the Both External Files , But Don't Know Why the Image is not showing as Pop up After Clicking On it

Kindly Help me in Finding the Problem for me

It will be great pleasure for me if anyone will help me.

Thanks

Comment: Fiddle seems to work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap requires jQuery.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="pop">
  <img src="http://patyshibuya.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/04.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;">
</a>

<a href="#" class="pop">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;">
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
          $('.pop').on('click', function() {
              $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
              $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
          });     
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Bro.
I forgot to Add jQuery.

Comment: NP. You should consider closing the question, it's no longer on-topic on SO if it was just a mistake/oversight like that.

Comment: Sorry, Did not get you